# Need help to make a specific design in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to make this following design in android: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04trS.jpg)

I have already made the right hand side part. I can't figure out how to make the left side. (Joined Dots)

This is my code for the right hand side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="2dp" android:left="10dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/lightGreen">
            </solid>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"></corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp" android:top="10dp" android:height="10dp" android:width="10dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/lightGreen" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: your left part is timelineview so you can use library like this https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android-vertical-stepper-view](https://github.com/liefery/android-vertical-stepper-view) library to achieve your "Joined Dots" look.

- It will be easier rather than implementing everything by yourself.
- you can even check the [sample app](https://github.com/liefery/android-vertical-stepper-view/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/liefery/android/vertical_stepper_view/sample) of using this library to better understand how to use it.

**Edit** - I have never worked with [Timeline-View](https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View) but it looks like another option that you can use as *@Ankit* mentioned